# iOS 設定画面で稀にProduct Nameがされている？

Tags: ios, iphone

原因がいまいち分からず、まだ一度しか見たことがない現象なので質問させていただきました。

今作成しているアプリでApp Storeからアプリをアップデート中に、iOSの設定画面を見て見るとDisplay Name(例:MyApp)を設定されているにも関わらず、Product Name（例：MyAppMaster）が表示されていました。

アップデート後に再度、設定画面を開いてみるとアプリ名はMyAppになっており、何度もTestFlightから前バージョンをインストールして、アップデートしてみても再現しない状態です。

どうか有識者のみなさまにお願いです。
どういった理由でこのような現象が起こり得るのか、ご助言のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

再現デバイス: iOS12.1.4 iPhone6
開発環境: xcode10.1 swift4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

原因がなんとなく分かったので、一応残しておきます。

設定画面で表示されているアプリ名はBundleDisplayNameの値を取ってきており、このBundleDisplayNameが取得出来なかった時の代わりにBundleNameの値が使われるそうです

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-109585

BundleNameのデフォルトの値が$(PRODUCT_NAME)で、取得先がTarget Nameだったことで起きたようでした。